# Display Word Document in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, ms-word

I would like to display a word document in HTML what would you suggest to do? I would like to have it as normal text displayed and the pictures should get displayed too.

Comment: Try use the <iframe> tag in html.

Comment: I am voting to close this citing, "Needs more focus"(already closed citing the same:)). You would want a DOCX to HTML converter for that. If you need to display images you will have to upload the docx to your file. Convert that to html and save your assets like images, audio, video to the server folders and llink them from there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible I think, I never saw that.

But you can make an embed of it as a pdf :

1. Save it as PDF
2. Upload it to your website (like an image or anything)
3. Code :

   < embed src="https://example.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">

And that's it :)